# how to include utility classes in eclipse (android programming)

Tags: android, eclipse, utility

I am doing Android programing with Eclipse (Helios), and I have some utility classes created. How do I set up Eclipse, so that if I use one of my utility classes it gets included when the project compiles?

Comment: Where are your utility classes? In the same project or a linked project?

Comment: You might find this example helpful: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/TicTacToeLib/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add them to the Build Path (Right click on Project > Build Path)